# Apply an operation to almost all fields of a document in MongodDB?

Tags: python, json, mongodb, pymongo

There are few (< 10) collections, for each collections I need to apply a fixed operation to certain fields of a document (will vary collection to collection). The operation needs to be applied to almost all fields, except few.

An approach I could think of:

1. To have a list of fields for each collection to which I needn't apply that operation, read all fields minus the ones present in the list and apply the operation.

Is there a better way to tackle this problem?

Answer (score 0):

yes if the number of exluded fields is very < to included fields, your approach seems right.
but As far as I know there is now way of sending a complete document to a mongo[s|d] and tell it to only skip certain fields.